# Connect from VM to Host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization, firewall, gateway

I installed ClearOS on a VM (vbox) and all other VM are connected via ClearOS.

I want to know if it's possible to connect my host OS and all other computers on physical LAN via ClearOS as gateway!

> ClearOS adapters:
>
> - Adapter1: bridge network
> - Adapter2: Internal Network

[image: click to see the Image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Unconfigure IP interface on host machine that was connecting it to internet. Simply remove IP address (ifconfig interfacename 0.0.0.0). Then make sure that default route is gone. After that set default route to internal interface of your virtual machine. There are other options but this one seems to be simplest.